# Problem with auto-updating column create_at

Tags: symfony

After `$this->em->flush();` updated columns create_at and update_at but need only update_at. I tried to fix trait-file with set\get but its not give result.

Comment: Please provide some code to let us understand what is exactly your problem :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `$this->em->flush();` creates the entity, it will update both field otherwise it should only update `updated_at` field.

Comment: thanks, I founded the mistake at the update method in entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bundle StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.
And activate the extensions what you want.

in yaml config you can activate timestampable.

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
```

and you can use TimestampableEntity in your entity like this.

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TokenRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="tokens")
 */
class Token
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

so it will update and create your entities dates. :)